# Trouble with Gitolite installation on CentOS 5.6

Tags: linux, git, repository, centos, gitolite

I followed the [official documentation guide](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html) on how to install Gitolite to create my own repository on a brand new CentOS server.

When I get to the part where I must put the following command:

```
gl-setup myPublicKey.pub
```

I get a `command not found` warning on terminal.

Somehow I need to put an alias or symbolic link to the `$HOME/bin/gl-setup`, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anybody know how to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the root method on CentOS 5.6, and while I was able to get it running, it was a total nightmare. I'd recommend `gl-easy-install` from your workstation if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just add "$HOME/bin" to your PATH.

Edit your $HOME/.bash_profile and append the line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin ; export PATH
```

to the end of it (I'm guessing that you're using the default bash shell). Source the file (or logout-login) and you *should* be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gl-easy-setup from the client side.